# How to locate a checkbox to verify its state using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, html-input

I am trying to figure out if a checkbox on our website is in a checked state or not. The HTML for the checkbox is as follows:

```
<input id="ID_StaffIsRostered" name="ID_Rostering" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-size="sm" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" onchange="toggleRosteredStaff()">
```

I've tried finding this via these locators:

1. `(By.ID, "ID_StaffIsRostered")`
2. `(By.XPATH, "input[@name='ID_Rostering']"`
3. `(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='ID_StaffIsRostered']")`
4. `(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/div/input")`
5. `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"label:nth-child(1) > .btn-light .toggle-off")`
6. `(By.XPATH,"//form[@id='ID_Form_Rostering']/div/div/div/label/div/div/label[2]")`
7. `(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/label/div/div/label[2]")`

Nothing has worked so far. I can however select the div containing the checkbox, and the labels that the checkboxes switch between depending on what it is toggle to, the HTML is:

```
<div class="toggle btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 7.5px; height: 26px; min-width: 38px;">
```

and for the labels:

```
<div class="toggle-group"><label class="btn btn-success btn-sm toggle-on">Yes</label><label class="btn btn-light btn-sm toggle-off">No</label><span class="toggle-handle btn btn-light btn-sm"></span></div>
```

What are some alternative ways I can achiever this? Currently I'm using Selenium 4.0.0 with Python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [HTML Specification for Boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute):

> A number of attributes are Boolean attributes. The presence of a
> boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
> absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
> or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
> canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

The *checked* attribute can be represented in either of the ways:

```
<input name=name id=id type=checkbox checked>
<input name=name id=id type=checkbox checked="">
<input name=name id=id type=checkbox checked="checked">
```

---

### Solution

To verify the state of the checkbox you can probe the *`checked`* attribute and you can use the following code block:

```
try:
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#ID_StaffIsRostered[name='ID_Rostering'][checked]")))
  print("Checkbox is in checked state")
except:
  print("Checkbox is in unchecked state")
```

Comment: This worked, thankyou. The issue ended up being my use of EC.visibility_of_element_located rather than EC.presence_of_element_located. I think because it's a bootstrapped checkbox, selenium would only look at the divs on top of the checkbox.

Again, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

1. the checked parameter of the checkbox will indicate whether it is checked or not, you can get the status of this parameter through xpath（.../input[@checked]）
2. carefully observe the website laws, whether the checked checkboxes have any special status, such as color, text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways I can think of.

```
element.get_attribute('checked')
```

Or you can query javascript.

```
return document.querySelector('input[name="ID_Rostering"]').checked;
```

As for trying xpath but its not always reliable.

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and not(@checked)]
```

for not checked

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked)]
```

for checked